# Имя класса для кнопки, которое вызывает действие

Tags: css, бэм

Есть блок, который скрыт и нужно показать его `.full-list.full-list--hidden`.

Как назвать кнопку, чтобы она по нажатию убирала `.full-list--hidden`?

Есть вариант назвать `.show-full-list`, но правильно ли это с точки зрения БЭМ?

Comment: Или лучше вообще не создавать класс, а добавить data-action="showFullList"?

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае класс лучше называть `.js-show-full-list`

Я просто добавляю в начале такого селектора js-'название'. Смотришь на html и понимаешь что к чему.